# Finding $n$ from the cumulative sum of the serie where $SUM(n) < \Pi < SUM(n+1)$

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

I have a serie of numbers:

$$S = {1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8, 1/9, 1/10, 1/20, 1/30, 1/40, 1/50, 1/60, 1/70, 1/80, 1/90, 1/100, 1/200, 1/300, 1/400, 1/500, 1/600, 1/700, 1/800, 1/900,...}$$

Which cumulative sum is:

$$\sum^{\inf}_{k=0}\sum^{9}_{x=1}\frac{1}{x10^k} = \frac{7129}{2268}$$

With the following function I know that there is a point when cumulative sum of the serie is less than $\Pi$ and more than $\Pi$:

$$f(z) :$$

$$\frac{(-2520 - 1260×z - 840×z^2 - 630×z^3 - 504×z^4 - 420×z^5 - 360×z^6 - 315×z^7 - 280×z^8)}{(252×(-10 + z^9))}$$

Sample results:

$$f(0) = 1.0$$
$$f(1) = \frac{7129}{2268} ≈ 3.143$$

I'm not sure if the funtion $f(z)$ is required for the task, but I'd like to find $n$ *th* item from the serie $S$ which meets criteria:

$$sum(S, n) < \Pi < sum(S, n+1)$$

---

Just for curiosity:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7129 (914 nth prime)

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2268 (2^2 × 3^4 × 7)

Function $f(z)$ plain number primes:

$$2^3×3^2×5×7 = 2520$$
$$2^2×3^2×5×7 = 1260$$
$$2^3×3×5×7  = 840$$
$$2×3^2×5×7  = 630$$
$$2^3×3^2×7  = 504$$
$$2^2×3×5×7  = 420$$
$$2^3×3^2×5  = 360$$
$$3^2×5×7  = 315$$
$$------------------$$
$$2^2×3^2×7  = 252$$

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to compute the sum block by block of 9 terms, since 
$$
\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{7129}{2520}
$$
Thus your sum (collecting the terms with the same power of $10$) is equal to
$$
\frac{7129}{2520}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{10^k} = \frac{7129}{2520}\frac{10^{n+1}-1}{9\cdot 10^n}
$$
So it is simple to see that this sum is smaller than $\pi$ for $n=2$ and greater than $\pi$ for $n=3$.

So, we know that at least the first $3\cdot 9$ terms are to be added (from $\frac{1}{1}$ to $\frac{1}{9\cdot 10^2}$) and their sum is $\frac{263773}{84000}=3.14015476\dots$.

Now we can manually add the terms $\frac{1}{1\cdot 10^3}$, $\frac{1}{2\cdot 10^3}$, $\frac{1}{3\cdot 10^3},\dots$, until we go over $\pi$.

It is easy to see that 
$$
\frac{263773}{8400}+\frac{1}{1000}=\frac{263857}{84000}=3.14115476\dots < \pi\,,
$$
and
$$
\frac{263773}{8400}+\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{2000}=\frac{263899}{84000}=3.14165476\dots > \pi\,,
$$

So, considering your initial sequence, with $27+1=28$ terms you are smaller than $\pi$, with $27+2=29$ terms you are above $\pi$.